# Understanding confidence bounds in logistic and multinomial regression

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

I used both logistic (binomial distribution) and multinomial regression on a range of different datasets. For simplicity, I only have one explanatory variable in the linear predictor.

I also calculated the confidence bounds for the predicted probabilities, following [this procedure](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect043.htm).

What I observed, is that for the large datasets my confidence intervals were much narrower than for smaller datasets, which I thought made sense. However, when I look at a diagnostic plot such as expected vs. observed counts, even for the large datasets there are some visible systematic deviations of the data from the fit which apparently are not reflected by the confidence intervals, which seem to underestimate such variations.

What I mean is, I would expect the CIs to be wider to reflect these deviations.

Any idea on why this would be the case? Or am I missing something in my interpretation / calculation of confidence intervals?

Comment: You need to say something about the nature of your data and the domain of your problem. Is there some source of heterogeneity you haven't accounted for? Perhaps some clustering or temporal aspect of the data?

Comment: My data consists of counts of items that reach a certain level of damage (1 to 5), for values of a continuous demand parameter i.e. the explanatory variable. So this is not a time series - although this may not be what you mean by "temporal aspect"?

Comment: One thing I know is that the demand parameter I use is not the only variable which influences the response in reality. However because measurements are not available for these other influential variables I cannot include them in the model. Maybe this means I cannot derive confidence intervals all together... I am not sure.